# Dart/Flutter check if value is an integer/whole number

Tags: flutter, dart, integer

How do I check if a value is a whole number (integer) or contains a decimal? In Javascript we have `isInteger` but I couldn't find the equivalent in Dart.

We seem to have checks for `isEven`, `isOdd`, `isFinite`, `isInfinite`, `isNaN` and `isNegative` but no `isInteger`?

Comment: Still no valid answers that actually work in Flutter.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Dart numbers (the type `num`) are either integers (type `int`) or doubles (type `double`).

It is easy to check if a number is an `int`, just do `value is int`.

The slightly harder task is to check whether a `double` value has an integer value, or no fractional part. There is no simple function answering that, but you can do `value == value.roundToDouble()`. This removes any fractional part from the `double` value and compares it to the original value. If they are the same, then there was no fractional part.

So, a helper function could be:

```
bool isInteger(num value) => 
    value is int || value == value.roundToDouble();
```

I use `roundToDouble()` instead of just `round()` because the latter would also convert the value to an integer, which may give a *different* value for large double values.

Another test for a `double` having an integer value could be `value % 1.0 == 0.0`, but it's not more readable, unlikely to be more efficient, and even though it does actually work, I had to check what `% 1.0` does for `double.infinity` (it gives NaN) before I could trust it.

Comment: This actually _does_ work, unlike the other answers. Although I would think this would be part of Dart. Since it has less useful functions like isOdd, is Even etc which are even simpler to check.

Comment: @lrn Would using `truncateToDouble` not be slightly simpler than using `roundToDouble`?

Comment: I'm surprised that there does not seem to be an equivalent to C's `modf` to extract the integral and fractional parts of a `double`.

Comment: It shouldn't matter which of `truncateToDouble`, `roundToDouble`, `floorToDouble` or `ceilToDouble` you use, except for performance. It does seem that `roundToDouble` is slower than the other three on the VM, and both `roundToDouble` and `truncateToDouble` are slower when compiled to JS and run in Chrome. Neither are so bad I'd care unless I know it's a bottleneck for my app (and then I'd check other browsers too).

Comment: Note that `1 is int` will work on Native and Web. However, `1 is double` will actually return `false` for Native and `true` for Web! And `1.0 is int` will return `true` for Web! It seems like the makers of Dart really don't want you to use this idiom, as they don't guarantee the result to match for all platforms. I advise against it, because it could be changed in the future. https://dart.dev/guides/language/numbers

Comment: If the goal is to detect non-fractional `num` values (which it is here), then `is int` is correct, and on the web, it's all you need (well, if you *want* to include the infinite values, otherwise you may need to add `&& x.isFInite`). The code above works for the current Dart number implementations, and if anything changes, it's likely going to be the web getting real integers (as a feature in JS or by or compiling to WASM instead of JS), and then it'll still be correct.
It's true that you should not use `is int` to deduce that the value is not a `double`.

Comment: Since Dart 3, `num` is now `sealed`, having just `int` and `double` as its subclasses. So it should feel way easier to satisfy this check.

Comment: Making `num` sealed really has no effect on this problem. It already was effectively sealed with final subclasses before, by special-casing. There have been no changes to the actual implementation, so everything is still the same.

Answer (score 22):

Use the modulo operator %:

```dart
  bool isInteger(num value) => (value % 1) == 0;
```

Same as an extension method:

```dart
  extension NumExtensions on num {
    bool get isInt => (this % 1) == 0;
  }
```

Usage:

```dart
  double d = 2.6;
  double d2 = 2.0;
  int i = 2;
  print(d.isInt); // returns false
  print(d2.isInt); // returns true
  print(i.isInt); // returns true
```

Comment: I am not sure about the speed of this compared to others, but I find the modulo operator way of doing it easier to understand. I think it comes to preference. I would however, avoid using an extension method on a native object as extensions can cause more confusion and are difficult to determine where they come from. I would instead create a helper class for working with numbers called something like Math

Answer (score 6):

```
void main() {
  int a = 10;
  print(a is int); // Prints true
}
```

OR

```
void main() {
  dynamic a = 10;
  print(a is int ? a/10 :"Not an int"); // Prints 1
}
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to work? `print((2 + 2) is int);` = true,  `print((2 / 2) is int);` = false ??

Comment: `print((2 / 2) is int);` and `print((2 + 2) is int);` both prints `true`

Comment: I'm not getting that in Flutter, which version of Dart is that? Are you checking it in Flutter?

Comment: I think you should remove your answer because it's confirmed that it does not work in Dart. It does not verify a whole number so it's misleading to others seeing your answer. It _does_ work in Dartpad because Dartpad compiles to javascript, but it does not work in actual Dart code like we see in Flutter.

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this and works just fine:

```dart
bool _isInteger(double value) => value == value.toInt();
```

Method `toInt()` drops the decimal part, so if after dropping this part nothing changed, it means it is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

To check the datatype of any variable in Dart, you can make use of the keyword *is*. For instance :

```
void main() {
     int x = 10;
     double y = 20;
     checkType(x, y);
    }

void checkType(dynamic x, dynamic y) {
  if (x is int) {
    print(x);
  } else {
    print(y);
  }
}
```

The code above will print 10 since the variable *x* inside the main function is an Integer Data type.

Answer (score 0):

I just make two extension method (in DART),
Here i get true if given number integer(whole) or false if given number if double(decimal).

Here `isInteger` method will give boolean value and `getDoubleOrInt` method will give String value which is integer or two decimal precise decimal string format value.

**Extension Method**

```
extension OnNumber on num {
  String get getDoubleOrInt {
    if (toString().split('.').length > 1) {
      if (int.parse(toString().split('.').elementAt(1)) > 0) {
        return toDouble().toStringAsFixed(2);
      } else {
        return toInt().toString();
      }
    } else {
      return toInt().toString();
    }
  }

  bool get isInteger {
    if (toString().split('.').length > 1) {
      if (int.parse(toString().split('.').elementAt(1)) > 0) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Application Example**

```
void main() {
  double x = 3.5999;
  
  print(x.isInteger); // false
  print(x.getDoubleOrInt); // 3.60
  
  int y = 123; 
  
  print(y.isInteger);  // true
  print(y.getDoubleOrInt); // 123
  
}
```

Hope you like this two method.